# vuejs refresh template after ajax return

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I'm trying to make my VueJS template refresh after an AJAX request.

At the page first loading my datas are correctly updated en the template is OK.

in my template i have this section that i want to be updated each time one of the task has changed :

```
<li v-for="(task,index) in tasks" @click="setCurrentTask(index)" :class="{'active' : currentTask.id == task.id}">
                        <span><i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i></span>{{ task.attributes.name }}
                        <a class="ui mini label" :class="task.attributes.state.attributes.name">{{ task.attributes.state.attributes.name }}</a><br>
                        <div class="details">
                            {{ currentTask.attributes.estimatedStart }}<br>
                            <i class="fas fa-play" @click="startTask(index)"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Then i have a request that says to change the state of a specific task to start it then it returns the task with the status updated :

```
export default {
    name: "fdr",
    data(){
        return {
            fdr:'',
            tasks:'',
            currentTask:null,
            currentIndex:null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setCurrentTask: function (index) {
            this.currentTask = this.tasks[index]
            this.currentIndex = index;
            if(this.currentTask.time != null){
                $('.time').html( this.currentTask.timer.getTimeValues().toString());
                $('#startDate').calendar();
            }
        },
        startTask(index){
            axios.get(this.$env_uri+'/api/task/'+this.tasks[index].id+"/start").then(function (resource) {
                this.tasks[index] = resource.body
            }.bind(this))
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.$http.get(this.$env_uri+'/api/fdr/' + this.$route.params.id)
            .catch(response => {
                return this.$router.push('/404')
            })
            .then(function (resource) {
                    this.fdr = resource.body
                    this.tasks = this.fdr.relationship.tasks
                    this.setCurrentTask(0);
                }
            );
    },
```

When this.task is updated VueJs is not refreshing my template to display the new status of the task. I can't find a way to do it... do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally misunderstod the issue first.

The problem is updating updating an index in an array. This is something that has to be done with `Array.$set(index, value)` since Vue don't have a way to tell if an index in an array is changed.

You can read more about it [here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)

Comment: The created function was already working great, your solution is working as mine. The probleme is when my startTask() is called. This function is updating this.ogmep but in my view nothing is updated....

Comment: ah alright, sorry for the misunderstanding. It looks like that you are updating an index of an array there. Vue don't have a way to tell when that happened so the way you do that is with `$set` 

So change that too: `this.tasks.$set(index, resource.body);`

Comment: Thank you so much ! $set is working great, i just had to correct the syntax with `this.$set(this.tasks,index,ressource.body);`

Comment: No problem, happy to help!